VS 2022 Could not Create React App with error message the sdk microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk/1.0.1184077 specified could not be found
I try to make a ReactJS as Frontend with .Net Core 6 as API Application, but as soon as I click create button there is a popup with error message like this :
The sdk microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk/1.0.1184077 specified could not be found
I have try to install the SDK, but the .nupkg file seems need to be install on a react project.
Also when I try to install microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk on my solution that currently only has .Net API part, it refuse to install because it is not compatible with existing project..
So it is a chicken and egg situation now..

Check your local nuget folder if it contains the package. Delete it and re-open VS. If it doesnt help clear your nuget cache from visual studio. Also verify if npm is installed correctly.

The reactjs and .net core application is inside the same projects?

@BrandoZhang No, but it is on the same solution.
When I make this question I can only manage to create a project for .Net API.
The reactJs project is not yet created

I have solved this problem with install nuget React.Core on my .net API project.
I have try to make a new solution using React And ASP.NET Core, and the problem is not occur again.

Actually before having problem with making new solution using "React And ASP.NET Core", the same problem also happening when I try to make a new solution using "Angular and ASP.Net Core".
And now the problem also gone.
